# Is it possible to have bluetooth pairing/bonding without user interaction?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible in Android (I'm interested in Android 4.0 and later) to have a complete bonding/pairing process without user interaction or is it a security feature that cannot be disabled?

The only way I see to start bonding/pairing is by using [BluetoothDevice.createBond()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond%28%29)

And it's documentation is not looking promising for me:

> Start the bonding (pairing) process with the remote device.
>
> This is an asynchronous call, it will return immediately. Register for ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED intents to be notified when the bonding process completes, and its result.
>
> Android system services will handle the necessary user interactions to confirm and complete the >bonding process.
>
> Requires BLUETOOTH_ADMIN.

Is there another way? Or maybe some settings/configurations that I can change?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to communicate with a bluetooth device. You can choose to "disable" the pairing "security feature".

With "BluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", the pair/bond process is needed and the process will be triggered if needed, because you are trying to "Create an RFCOMM BluetoothSocket ready to start a **secure** outgoing connection to this remote device using SDP lookup of uuid."(which from android API Doc)

With "BluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", the pair/bond process is not needed.

So, if your communication message is confidential, you need the bond process. If your communication not confidential, insecure socket maybe what you want.